# TFS build modifying website folder structure

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, wix, continuous-integration

In my solution I have a basic ASP.NET MVC website and a Wix Project. To identify the files that need installed I'm using Heat (a Wix component) to index the build output. This is part of a post-build event. It works perfectly on my local machine when building in Visual Studio 2015.

My problem occurs when checked-in and the CI (TFS Build) builds it. The differences are:

- The contents of the **bin** folder is placed directly in the build folder
- The rest of the website is placed under a new _PublishedWebsites folder

This means many of the references get broken. For example when dropping the _PublishedWebsites folder into IIS breaks (as .net cannot locate the contents of Bin)

After much research on the subject, and many attempts to pass MSBuild parameters, I'm reaching the end of my efforts.

Is there a way for a build in TFS to leave file locations intact without copying  and creating new folders?

If not what is the recommended way to get a deployment ready site (in a single folder) from TFS?

Comment: Ensure that you have not DeployOnBuild defined to true in your project file or in MSbuild arguments

Comment: Can you share the settings of VSBuild step in your build definition?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT - Nope. I may need to add some condition depending on dev / CI build

Comment: Can you try adding following arguments to VS Build step in your build definition: "/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"", this will generated a web deployment package.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT - Thanks Eddie. The trouble is it's already generating what looks like a deployment (_PublishedWebsites folder) and I'd prefer a way to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Then you can simply remove all these arguments. By the way, the "bin" folder is included in the web package folder at my side.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a **Copy Files** task to copy bin folder to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\_PublishedWebsites`, check the screenshot below:

[image]